# Automatic registration in web-catalogs and SEO

Tags: seo, tools

They are a lot of tools, that can automatically submit my website to thousands of web-catalogs.

Is it a good practice to increate rankings ?

What are pros and cons against it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pros:

Cons: These links are worthless as they are almost certainly considered link farms (and if you ever link back to one of them you risk being considered part of it and getting penalized or banned yourself). And even if they aren't, there are so many links on those pages that what little value there is available is diluted the point where there is no more value. And that's assuming they have any value at all and the odds are they don't since they will have little no links pointing to them and they're almost certainly off topic. A lot of the sites they claim to submit to also no longer exist so you're getting less linking opportunities then you think.

In short, this is a waste of time

Answer (score 1):

No it won't help much for rankings or useful visitors.  Search engines look for relevant links and largely ignore link catalog/directory style sites.